# Why do some developers declare String objects in their Interfaces in Java, and how does it work?

Tags: java, interface

When I was analysing a code in my project, I came accross this situation.
I have got an Interface with complete String constants declaration as below

```
public interface SampleInterface {
    String EXAMPLE_ONE = "exampleOne";
    String USER_ID     = "userId";

    public void setValue();
}
```

If any class implements this `SampleInterface` interface, what happens to the variables it declares?

- Does the inherited class get access to all the variables?
- Does the implemented class needs to override the declarations?
- What might be the purpose of declaring the String variables in an interface, when we could use an abstract class for this purpose?

Also, what is the best strategy:

1. A class with the final static fields and a private constructor?
2. An Interface with the variables as seen above?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## It's a Common Java Idiom

In an interface in Java, all members are **implicitly** `public`, and fields in particular are implicitly `public static final`. **You DON'T have a choice.** If you try to use any other permission level than public, the compiler would scream at you as it wouldn't make any sense.

So any implementing class will indeed **inherit the members, including these static constant fields**.

## Why do People Use this Idiom?

There are several reasons why you would do this in an interface, and usually it is to use it as a **constant store**. This idiom is used to simply bundle constants together in one place, not necessarily to have the interface used as part of an inheritance tree in an OO way.

So you can call as usuall `MyInterface.MY_CONST` to access one of your constants.

You would do this over an interface usually when you don't need any behavior to be defined, so when you don't need any methods. It's really just a static store (often, the interface is made `final` itself as well). You could use an `abstract class` for this as well, for instance if you want to encapsulate and hide details of an implementation. But in this case, where you have both fields and methods, usually your objective is simply to **provide some constants and a contract for sub-classes**.

Considering in your case there's also a method signature as part of your interface, there's obviously an intent to implement this interface. In which case you can still access your data as either:

- `MyInterface.MY_CONST`,
- or `MyExtendingClass.MY_CONST`,
- or `instanceOfMyExtendingClass.MY_CONST`.

---

## More Information

For more information, have a look at:

- this [FAQ entry](http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-Interface.shtml#interfacemembers) and the ones that follow it,
- comments by Anon and Jeff regarding misuses of this form,
- [Enum type as introduced since Java 5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) (which, and as mentioned by John, would in many cases definitely be a better idea: more elegant, with the added benefit of type-safety when passing it, and using fairly optimized constructs to lookup and manipulate the values).

Comment: Your say is to put all the constants in Interface and access them during my execution, Suppose if any class implements this Interface, what happens to those variables?

Comment: Then you can access them either via `MyInterface.MY_CONSTANT` or `MyExtendingClass.MY_CONSTANT`. Or even `instanceOfMyExtendingClass.MY_CONSTANT`, as they are `public static final`.

Comment: In the implementing class, you can also just refer to it as `MY_CONSTANT` (which is the initial reason for the whole "interface of constants" anti-pattern). However, if that's specifically what you're after, the `import static` declaration was added for a reason.

Comment: It should be noted that using an interface strictly as a "constants store" is a terrible practice.  Better is to store constants in a final class with a private constructor.  Best is to store the constants in an interface/class that actually defines behavior related to those constant values.

Comment: @Anon: right I had actually forgotten that this was the reason. For me that was mostly just to gather them in some place when it makes sense, but that's also a possible abuse. Static import is indeed better... but also abused...

Comment: @Jeff: Note that I didn't say it was a good practice, just that it was a common idiom usually regarded as acceptable.

Comment: @Jeff: Actually it seems like I edited away the "regarded as acceptable" bit. Or I dreamed it (it's a bit 3.51am here). I referred to your comment and Anon's in an edit. Thank you.

Comment: If multiple classes need access to a constant in order to control functionality, I find that it is worth looking to see if those constants could belong to an enum. The enum becomes a "smart constant" that contains code as well, removing program control from code that probably does not need it and placing it all in one location that is easier to maintain.

Comment: @John: I totally agree that an enum is better. I've actually never written an interface like this myself in 7 years, and since Java 5 there definitely rarely a good reason for it. I'm just answering the question :)

Comment: @John: added this as an end note the answer as well. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note: only  **Fields** of an interface are implicitly `public static final`; methods, for example, are not implicitly `final`. (The JLS states: “The members of an interface type may be classes, interfaces, fields, and methods.”)

Comment: @Carlos: thanks correcting my terminology. Originally was just mentioning the fact that members were implicitly public in interfaces, so that included methods as well. Good catch.